# Телеграм бот на aiogram, кнопки Reply. Работает только одна команда

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при нажатии reply кнопки "Поддержка" всё работает хорошо. Но при нажатии других кнопок ничего не происходит, хотя обработка этих кнопок прописана в коде.
Вот код бота:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton

BOT_TOKEN = "Токен"

bot = Bot(BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

kb = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
b1 = KeyboardButton("help")
b2 = KeyboardButton("❤Поддержка❤")
b3 = KeyboardButton("❤")
kb.add(b1).add(b2).insert(b3)

HELP_COMMAND = """
/help-Список команд
/start-Начать работу с ботом"""


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start_message(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("<b>Добро пожаловать в наш бот! Мы очень рады вам)</b>",
                         parse_mode="HTML")
    await bot.send_sticker(message.from_user.id,
                           sticker="CAACAgIAAxkBAAEGENdjRqYnLj0GfoaH3ShZmgKbpoe0OwACBQADwDZPE_lqX5qCa011KgQ",
                           reply_markup=kb)
    await message.delete()


@dp.message_handler()
async def support(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == "❤Поддержка❤":
        await message.answer("Поддержка - @CosMiX1")


commands=["help"]
async def help_message(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(text=HELP_COMMAND,
                         parse_mode="HTML")


async def on_startup(_):
    print("Бот успешно запущен!")


@dp.message_handler()
async def heart(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == "❤":
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                             photo='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHfQfXQD-FhEfRlBCrWZiLi5PMIYWLRr2d6A&usqp=CAU')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Все ваши сообщения ловит верхний handler. У вас есть два варианта:

Фильтр:

```
@dp.message_handler(text='текст вашей кнопки')
async def handler(message: types.Message):
#выполняем код
```

Проверки внутри хендлера:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def handler(message: types.Message):
    if message.text=='1 кнопка':
        #действие
    elif message.text=='2 кнопка':
        #другое действие
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, пойду проверять!